# Serious Problems with MongoDB's Performance and Data Security

Tags: performance, mongodb

I'm using mongodb 2.4.3,and I have encountered some severe problems:

Firstly, **performance**:

There are about 40000 items in my mongodb's server log as follows:

```
Fri Oct 18 03:10:15.396 [conn20627] update onlinetime.online_2013_10_18 query: { _id: 63545 } update: { $inc: { olt: 12085 } } nscanned:1 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:1 locks(micros) w:89 628ms
Fri Oct 18 03:10:15.396 [conn20658] update onlinetime.online_2013_10_18 query: { _id: 101599 } update: { $inc: { olt: 15018 } } nscanned:1 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:1 locks(micros) w:83 625ms
Fri Oct 18 03:10:15.396 [conn20656] update onlinetime.online_2013_10_18 query: { _id: 143782 } update: { $inc: { olt: 14897 } } nscanned:1 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:1 locks(micros) w:75 600ms
Fri Oct 18 03:10:15.396 [conn20629] update onlinetime.online_2013_10_18 query: { _id: 98588 } update: { $inc: { olt: 13895 } } nscanned:1 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:1 locks(micros)  w:82 610ms
Fri Oct 18 03:10:15.396 [conn20670] update onlinetime.online_2013_10_18 query: { _id: 145266 } update: { $inc: { olt: 17629 } } nscanned:1 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:1 locks(micros) w:79 593ms
Fri Oct 18 03:10:15.396 [conn20642] update onlinetime.online_2013_10_18 query: { _id: 71860 } update: { $inc: { olt: 15026 } } nscanned:1 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:1 locks(micros) w:79 604ms
```

What do these logs mean? Does a simple update by `_id` like `{ $inc: { olt: 12085 }` really take 628 milliseconds to complete?

There are only 20000 records or so in collection `online_2013_10_18`.

**Are there some serious performance problems with mongodb? Or did I just misuse it?** And even stranger is a log item show that:

```
update taxilogs.log_PUSH_2013_10_18 query: { idxs: 1827626800 } update: { $addToSet: { acks: { rid: 36045, date: new Date(1382076054148) } }, $inc: { acks_c: 1 } } nscanned:1 nmoved:1 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:3575082 3575ms
```

A update takes 3575 millis seconds to complete?

Secondly: **Data loss**:

From my application's log, I'm sure that a update has posted to mongodb. But this is what I see in the log:

```
update:{ "idxs" : 1827771018},{ "$addToSet" : { "acks" : { "rid" : 130284 , "date" : { "$date" : "2013-10-18T05:27:08.358Z"}}} ,"$inc" : { "acks_c" : 1}}.
but when I query data using find({ "idxs" : 1827771018},{acks_c:1,recs_c:1}),mongodb returns { "_id" : ObjectId("5260b3450cf2f82eef378e8d"), "recs_c" : 99 }
```

`acks_c` did not get updated, what's wrong? No exception was found in mongodb's server log.

**Is it possible that mongodb lost some update silently?**

Comment: MongoDB lives and dies by its indexes - please can you post the indexes that are defined for the collection?

Comment: addToSet will only add it to the array if it is not in the array already. hence increasing complexity. Also notice nmoved:1 , this means that your document has outgrown its priorly allocated space and was moved on disk, most likely increasing the time. The right most ms is indeed the process time.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.I have found the problem:IO is to busy,iostat shows that the io usage(%util) is nearly 100% all the time,and there are  500+ writes per second.There is a collection with about 40 million records in it,and every second about 2000 records are inserted（in batch way）into this collection.I wonder,under such circumstance, why there are 500+ writes every seconds? How dose mongodb manage io flushing?